What's so difficult about modeling the front end of the curve
I never worked on front-end sofr curve construction but wondering why it is much harder than the longer end.
For me building a curve is just solving a minimization problem where you have $n$ degrees of freedom. So each one of your instrument can be calculated as a function of these degrees of freedom: $f_i(m_1, ... m_n)$, then you find the $m_i$ such that it minises the MSE between the observed market prices and the $f_i$.
Why can't you apply directly this minimization problem for SOFR futures to build the front end of the curve?
It seems like there are issues, but I don't understand what are the issues? and why the front end of the curve is much harder to build than the long end.

I would say there are a few things:
Firstly, you often wish to capture effects that are not directly linked to the liquid instruments that construct your curve. E.g. stepping on meeting effective dates, rather than on IMM dates, or rolling monthly tenor dates.
See here: In rateslib curve construction, how to control the jump size in step daily forward (log_linear), when i have 2 nodes on 1 instrument?
Secondly you may need to capture overwhelming effects that are political or regulatory in nature, not economic. See here: https://rateslib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/z_turns.html
You may also want to blend interpolation styles between a short end and a long end which is essentially a hyper-parameter choice, so you must be able to add this into your problem.
And finally, once you have managed to do all of the above you have to have done it in such a way as to make risk metrics worthwhile to the market-maker. Even if you can find a way to get everything to work to generate good curves you may end up with unhelpful looking risk sensitivities, and therefore have to fine tune the solution.
The long end doesn't usually suffer any of these issues. It's usually quite straight forward since the market instruments, where to place degrees of freedom, etc. nicely align and avoid any of these secondary concerns.

I agree and further point out that the ‘best’ curve construction does not necessarily minimize  MSE (for example meeting date step function)
